# Simple Responsive page causes Chrome process to freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Chrome is locking up with the following code.  Chrome will go into an infinite spin and stop logging to the console after a few resize events or maybe even 1.  Sometimes I have to kill the Chrome process.  I can't reproduce it in FF or IE.  I also cannot reproduce the issue with [similar code](http://jsfiddle.net/36QSW/) that flips out div background colors rather than stylesheets.

The three stylesheets simply change the `background-color`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link id="size-stylesheet"  rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/wide.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This page is Responsive!</h1>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function adjustStyle(width) {
                    console.log('adjusting style...');
                    width = parseInt(width);                                        
                    if (width < 1283) {
                        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "/Content/narrow.css");
                    } else if ((width >= 1283) && (width < 1419)) {
                        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "/Content/medium.css");
                    } else {
                        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "/Content/wide.css");
                    }
                }

                $(function () {
                    adjustStyle($(this).width());
                    $(window).resize(function () {
                        console.log('resize fired...');
                        adjustStyle($(this).width());
                    });
                });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, I need to support non-HTML5 browsers such as IE8 and IE7.  So any solution needs to account for this.

Comment: Why don't you simply use CSS media queries instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Media Queries do not support older browsers (IE8 and below).  I have to ensure these browsers work too.

Comment: How many phones that would benefit from a responsive web site run IE 8 or older?

Comment: (In other words, 'working' in IE doesn't always mean 'working the same' as the rest of the browsers. It's often OK to give IE users a different experience)

Comment: you could also import the html5 script and still use media queries?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Did you report it? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use media queries.

Then, If you *have* to support <=IE8, use IE conditional comments to load your JS workaround just for those browsers:

```
<![if lte IE 8]>
<script src="IEsucks.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

That way you aren't penalizing good browsers with extra JS, and your site is already future proof.

(All that said: I would question the requirement that your responsive site has to work in old versions of IE. Do you really have a lot of users of your site that insist on using an old version of IE on their cell phone?)

Comment: I'm using Responsive as a technique to support variations in screen resolution and clunky wide data in an easily supportable fashion.  This app is for the medical industry where IE8 and windows XP are quite common.  However, other users run the latest browsers as well.

Comment: Sad but true...our medical industry runs on IE and XP. :) That said, this advice should still work. Leverage the 'proper' media queries and then, as needed, come back and apply JS just for IE.

Comment: Ultimately this is the only thing that worked.  Good answer.  I posted an answer to specify exactly how I used media queries to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JS, you can use `matchMedia` to set up media query conditions:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the view port is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the view port is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Here is [an article on CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) (which are also used in JS as the argument to `matchMedia`).

For more practical examples have a look at the code of some CSS framework, e.g. Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation.

There is a polyfill for **compatibility with IE <= 8** in JavaScript: [paulirish / matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/). You just include it before the other scripts, maybe in a MS conditional comment.

Or just write CSS and use a JS polyfill for that: [scottjehl / Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Answer (score 1):

Apply media queries, puts the rules you have in your css files inside each of this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1283px) {
    /* narrow */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1419px) {
    /* medium */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1419px) {
    /* wide */
}
```

Comment: But for better responsive solution try bootstrap instead: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I have bootstrap.  It's great for the one control that I have on the page that is from their UI library.  I need the rest of the content to be responsive too.  Also, I need a solution that works on IE8 and IE7.

Answer (score 1):

The following code switches out stylesheets based on the current browser width.  I tested it in IE7, IE10, Chrome v33 and FF v28.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>    
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1282px)" href="Content/narrow.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1293px) and (max-width: 1419px)" href="Content/medium.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1420px)" href="Content/wide.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/narrow.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function adjustStyle(width) {
                width = parseInt(width);

                if (width < 1283) {
                    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "Content/narrow.css");
                } else if ((width >= 1283) && (width < 1419)) {
                    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "Content/medium.css");
                } else {
                    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "Content/wide.css");
                }
            }

            $(function () {
                adjustStyle($(this).width());
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    adjustStyle($(this).width());
                });
            });
        </script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This page is Responsive!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

A few things worth noting:

- Don't use Javascript in Chrome to switch stylesheets on window resize.
- jQuery 2.X does not support IE7.
- Media queries are great for HTML5 browsers.  Otherwise, add HTML5 support as a polyfill (E.G. html5.js as shown here).  And switch out CSS sheets using JavaScript.
- The code makes use of [Downlevel-revealed conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment) to conditionally run code on non-IE browsers
- For testing, create the 3 CSS files and simply change `body {background-color: }`

Answer (score 0):

You call adjustSstyle too much. 1st call on init, then it probably changes the size and calls it again from resize. Also not sure why your code ins't embedded in head.

Comment: I think the issue is a deadlock.  If the event were fired too many times I would expect `console.log` to write out in succession before the process froze and eventually tossed out a stackoverflow exception.  Just a guess.

Comment: Not if your browser hangs before it can output to console

Answer (score 0):

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ErURP/4/

Implement a callback feature using `setTimeout`, `clearTimeout` and http://yepnopejs.com:

```
$(function(){
  $narrow_css = "http://f.cl.ly/items/3Y2P2q022R0B3X163c31/narrow.css";
  $medium_css = "http://f.cl.ly/items/3c2P3Z180l1s0j3S2v3k/medium.css";
  $wide_css = "http://f.cl.ly/items/2i0l3s1Z3K262z3X2X1e/wide.css";
  $resize_timer = null;
  $resize_timeout = 100;
  $css_tags = ['narrow','medium','wide'];

  function remove_css_tag(arr) {
    $.each(arr, function(i,v) {$('head [href*="'+v+'"]').remove();});
  }
  function resize_callback() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    remove_css_tag($css_tags);
    console.log('resize fired');
    console.log('screen width: ' + window.screen.width);
    console.log('window width: ' + width);

    if (width < 500) {
      yepnope.injectCss($narrow_css);
    } else if ((width >= 500) && (width <= 850)) {
      yepnope.injectCss($medium_css);
    } else {
      yepnope.injectCss($wide_css);
    } 
  } 

  $(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout($resize_timer);
    $resize_timer = setTimeout(resize_callback, $resize_timeout);
  });

  // init
  resize_callback();
});
```

Comment: This one freezes up as well.

Comment: Seems to be environment or version related—I have no problems with running that code in production and that's after QA runs it on many browsers… What versions of OS/Chrome/jQuery are you on? I'm using OS X 10.9.2 / Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152 / jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey on second thought, I'm executing css changes within the block and not setting an href to external stylesheet url… You could add a namespace to each of the three stylesheets and load them  all on page load—then change body class like: `$('body').addClass('narrow')`, etc.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I updated the code to use remote stylesheets and a jQuery plugin: [http://yepnopejs.com](http://yepnopejs.com). I'm curious to know if this updated code works for you…